# Button background color is not updating when button clicked

Tags: wpf, styles

My WPF application is not updating button background for when button is clicked AND mouse cursor is over it. The backgrund color is still light green. Other property changes are working ok. What is wrong?

File ControlStyles.xaml

```
...
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButton">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"/>       
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Control.FontStyle" Value="Italic"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Red"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="black"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Control.Foreground" Value="Firebrick"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Control.Background" Value="Yellow"></Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
...
```

Window.xaml

```
...
<Button Name="btn7" Content="7" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Click="btn7_Click"/>
        <Button Name="btn8" Content="8" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Click="btn8_Click"/>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this solves your problem :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButton">

    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"/>            
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Control.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="Control.FontStyle" Value="Italic"></Setter>
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Red"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>
            <Trigger.ExitActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="DarkCyan"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Black"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.ExitActions>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="Button.IsPressed" Value="true">
            <Trigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Yellow"/>
                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Button.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Firebrick"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </Trigger.EnterActions>                    
        </Trigger>                
    </Style.Triggers>

</Style>
```

Comment: mouse over: is not working at all (background color is not changing). button click : works in strange way: it changes color when mouse cursor is off the button

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution with usage of ControlTemplate. It's important to use x:Name and  TargetName inside of it.

ControlTemplate.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButtonTemplate">
        <Border x:Name="tempBorder" CornerRadius="20" Margin="4" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" Background="Gold">
            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="8,6,8,6" ContentSource="Content" />
        </Border>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="tempBorder" Property="Background" Value="MediumVioletRed"/>
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="tempBorder" Property="Background" Value="LightPink"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    </ControlTemplate>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

ConstrolStyles.xaml:

```
...
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" x:Key="MyButton">
<!-
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkCyan"/>
```

-->
            
            
        
    ...

Window.xaml:

```
...
 <Button Name="btnAdd" Content="Add" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource MyButton}" Template="{StaticResource MyButtonTemplate}" />
...
```

App.xampl:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             >
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/MyColors.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ControlStyles.xaml"/>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles/ControlTemplates.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```